# How to achive below result using provided array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm builing notifications component where I want to sort notification by dates and display them.

Can someone give me a hint to achieve that?

How can I do it over a following array ?

[image]

Array :

```
   notificationRows: Array(25)
    0:
    notificationRow:
    fee: "20 TEST"
    id: "1.11.191431"
    info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.00021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
    key: "1.11.191431"
    time: "2022-05-17 16:54:21"
    type: "transfer"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    unread: false
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    1:
    notificationRow:
    fee: "20 TEST"
    id: "1.11.191430"
    info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.012 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
    key: "1.11.191430"
    time: "2022-05-17 14:52:39"
    type: "transfer"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    unread: false
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    2:
    notificationRow:
    fee: "20 TEST"
    id: "1.11.191427"
    info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.0021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
    key: "1.11.191427"
    time: "2022-05-17 14:34:15"
    type: "transfer"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    unread: false
```

My expected result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array with descending dates, use `sort()` and `getTime()` for dates.
And in the return of your component, use `map()` to return an HTML element for each array item.
example using a function component

```
function App(props) {
  const {arr} = props;
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const date1 = new Date(a.notificationRow.time);
    const date2 = new Date(b.notificationRow.time);
    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
  })
  
  return (
    {
      arr.map((elem, i) => (<div key={i}>whatever you want here</div>))
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my query is not resolved yet, I'm not sure how can I can display the notifications as per last image. Like consider there are 5 notifications on today.. so all five must be renered under the today's label.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array.sort()` function in JavaScript to sort by date.

```js
const notificationRows = [
    {
      notificationRow: {
        fee: "20 TEST",
        id: "1.11.191431",
        info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.00021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]",
        key: "1.11.191431",
        time: "2022-05-17 16:54:21",
        type: "transfer",
        unread: false
      }
    },
    {
      notificationRow: {
        fee: "20 TEST",
        id: "1.11.191430",
        info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.012 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]",
        key: "1.11.191430",
        time: "2022-05-17 14:52:39",
        type: "transfer",
        unread: false
      }
    },
    {
      notificationRow: {
        fee: "20 TEST",
        id: "1.11.191427",
        info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.0021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]",
        key: "1.11.191427",
        time: "2022-05-17 14:34:15",
        type: "transfer",
        unread: false
      }
    }
  ];
    const sorted = constarr.sort(
    (a, b) =>
// return sorted date by newest. if want sort by old use Date.parse(a.notificationRow.time) - Date.parse(b.notificationRow.time) 
      Date.parse(b.notificationRow.time) - Date.parse(a.notificationRow.time) 
  );
  console.log("sorted", sorted);
```

Since you use react and you may use this sorted by time notifications to display, set this sorted arrays to the react state and render accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this. But my query is not resolved yet, I'm not sure how can I can display the notifications as per last image. Like consider there are 5 notifications on today.. so all five must be renered under the today's label.

Comment: @VijayThopate then you will have to use library like moment.js, datefns. Do you want to sort only by date or both date & time?

Comment: Only by dates. Also may be I need to filter them by dates ?